# Sign Spring WebClient HTTP request with AWS

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I would like to [AWS sign](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html) my HTTP request fired by reactive [WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html) of Spring. To sign the request I need access to the followings: URL, HTTP method, query parameters, headers and request body bytes.

I started with writing an [ExchangeFilterFunction](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ExchangeFilterFunction.html). Due to [ClientRequest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ClientRequest.html) interface I can access everything there I need, except the request body:

```
@Component
public class AwsSigningInterceptor implements ExchangeFilterFunction
{
    private final AwsHeaderSigner awsHeaderSigner;

    public AwsSigningInterceptor(AwsHeaderSigner awsHeaderSigner)
    {
        this.awsHeaderSigner = awsHeaderSigner;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<ClientResponse> filter(ClientRequest request, ExchangeFunction next)
    {
        Map<String, List<String>> signingHeaders = awsHeaderSigner.createSigningHeaders(request, new byte[]{}, "es", "us-west-2"); // should pass request body bytes in place of new byte[]{}

        ClientRequest.Builder requestBuilder = ClientRequest.from(request);

        signingHeaders.forEach((key, value) -> requestBuilder.header(key, value.toArray(new String[0])));

        return next.exchange(requestBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

In older spring versions we used [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) with a [ClientHttpRequestInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestInterceptor.html). In that case the bytes of the body were exposed, so signing was possible.

As I see in case of [WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html) Spring handles the body as a [Publisher](https://www.reactive-streams.org/reactive-streams-1.0.0-javadoc/org/reactivestreams/Publisher.html), so I'm not sure if an [ExchangeFilterFunction](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ExchangeFilterFunction.html) is a good place to start.

How should I sign the HTTP request?

Comment: can't you get the bytes by `request.body().toString().getBytes()`?

Comment: @ThomasAndolf no, because it returns a BodyInserter which is not the actual body. See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ClientRequest.html#body--

Comment: Is it possible now?

Comment: Not that I know of. I worked it around by serializing request body and calculating signing headers before sending the request.

Comment: Can you send a snippet code?

Comment: I know this question is quite outdated but, anyone has a breakthrough on this issue?

Comment: @bsferreira You can see my answer

Answer (score 1):

I came with the following solution:

```kotlin
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMapAdapter
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ClientRequest
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsCredentialsProvider
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.signer.Aws4Signer
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.signer.AwsSignerExecutionAttribute
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.interceptor.ExecutionAttributes
import software.amazon.awssdk.http.SdkHttpFullRequest
import software.amazon.awssdk.http.SdkHttpMethod
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region
import java.util.function.Function

class WebClientAwsSigner(
    private val body: String? = null,
    private val signer: Aws4Signer,
    private val awsCredentialsProvider: AwsCredentialsProvider,
    private val serviceName: String,
    private val region: Region,
) : Function<ClientRequest, Mono<ClientRequest>> {

    override fun apply(request: ClientRequest): Mono<ClientRequest> {
        val requestBuilder = SdkHttpFullRequest.builder()
            .method(SdkHttpMethod.fromValue(request.method().name()))
            .uri(request.url())
            .apply {
                if (body != null) {
                    contentStreamProvider { body.byteInputStream() }
                }
            }
            .headers(request.headers())

        val attributes = ExecutionAttributes()
        attributes.putAttribute(
            AwsSignerExecutionAttribute.AWS_CREDENTIALS,
            awsCredentialsProvider.resolveCredentials(),
        )
        attributes.putAttribute(AwsSignerExecutionAttribute.SERVICE_SIGNING_NAME, serviceName)
        attributes.putAttribute(AwsSignerExecutionAttribute.SIGNING_REGION, region)

        val signedAwsRequest = signer.sign(requestBuilder.build(), attributes)
        val signedClientRequest =
            ClientRequest.from(request)
                .headers {
                    it.clear()
                    it.addAll(MultiValueMapAdapter(signedAwsRequest.headers()))
                }
                .build()

        return Mono.just(signedClientRequest)
    }
}

    private fun signedAwsWebClient(body: String? = null): WebClient = webclient
        .mutate().filter(
            ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor(
                WebClientAwsSigner(body, Aws4Signer.create(), DefaultCredentialsProvider.create(), "es", Region.US_EAST_1),
            ),
        )
        .build()
```

GitHub: https://github.com/kkocel/webclient-signed-request-to-aws

Comment: This is great and just what I was looking for! AWS documentation is just unusable, but you helped us out. Thank you very much.